# docker-compose Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory /index.html

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, express, docker-compose

I have angular 8 as client side, server side as node and mysql as bd

**server app is up on localhost:3000**

```
node package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch-changes": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*' -e ts,tsx --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
```

**angular just builds into dist folder and i use one from server side:**

```
angular package.json:
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
........
```

**index.ts**

```js
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, '../../file-manager/dist/file-manager')));
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/api', new Router().routes);
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: join(__dirname, '../../file-manager/dist/file-manager') });
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if(err) {
    res.status(500).json({message: err.human || 'Internal Server Error'});
    return next(err);
  }
  return next();
});


console.log('PORT IS  ', port);
app.listen(port);
```

**\file-manager.docker\dev.dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**\server.docker\dev.dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "watch-changes"]
```

**When try docker-compose down and after docker-compose up:**

```js
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./file-manager
      dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
    image: file-manager-client-dev
    container_name: file-manager-client-dev
    ports:
      - "4000:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./file-manager/src:/usr/src/app/src

  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
    image: file-manager-server-dev
    container_name: file-manager-server-dev
    ports:
      - "8000:3000"
    external_links:
      - client
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql: # name of the third service
    build:
      context: ./mysql
      dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
    container_name: mysql-container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

and enter http://localhost:8000/ I see

> {"message":"Internal Server Error"}

on white page of browser

When I 'ng build' and 'npm run watch-changes' separately all works

**docker-compose ps**

```js
file-manager-client-dev   docker-entrypoint.sh npm start   Up      0.0.0.0:4000->4200/tcp
file-manager-server-dev   docker-entrypoint.sh npm r ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->3000/tcp
mysql-container           docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

**docker images**

```js
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
file-manager-client-dev        latest              24d9f5c92c12        17 minutes ago      1.51GB
file-manager-server-dev        latest              02b5dd9cac83        25 minutes ago      1.03GB
angular-8-file-manager_mysql   latest              4191cb9d3c3f        26 minutes ago      437MB
node                           10                  a68faf70e589        4 days ago          904MB
node                           latest              977e59b234b7        4 days ago          908MB
mysql                          5                   cd3ed0dfff7e        5 days ago          437MB
```

**logs**

**docker container logs file-manager-server-dev**

```
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/src/file-manager/dist/file-manager/index.html'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/src/file-manager/dist/file-manager/index.html'
```

***docker tries find index.html in file-manager-server-dev image but need to look for in file-manager-client-dev, how to specify it? Help please***

Comment: What does the log contain? I cannot think of any situation where an error 500 is thrown, but nothing is written to the log files. Additionally, are you sure that this is in any way related to Docker itself? According to `docker ps`, your containers were started properly

Comment: The error is being thrown from `index.ts`. Check your container logs

Comment: @NicoHaase, how can I display client log if it needs? container for client is missing, addd server log

Comment: @AyushGupta, added info

Comment: @NicoHaase, I think dist/file-manager/index.html path is wrong in vm, because I just removed dist folder and tried 'npm run watch-changes' get same error outside of docker build